# Is there any metric to evaluate output probabilities' precision in classification models?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, probability

I am currently developing a model in Python and Keras for a binary classification task (success/failure). My aim is to generate success probabilities for each observation so that I can use them later on in another task.

Do you know of any metric that quantifies the accuracy of these probabilities individually (and not the overall accuracy of the model)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using a metric like the [`Brier score`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brier_score)?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I checked the Brier score on Wikipedia but it seems to be nothing more that a simple MSE but is an interesting decomposition of the formula nonetheless ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brier_score#Two-component_decomposition ). This is kind of a biais_squared + variance decomposition per prediction group and could be used in my case but the problem remains in the choice of groups large enough to be non empty and yet not too large to have close predicted probabilities.

Any advice about choosing the 'right' group is welcome.